# Angular cli not installed in Windows 10

Tags: node.js, angular, windows-10, angular-cli

After changing OS from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 angular cli not being installed. It throwing following warning.

[image]

I have installed latest node.js - 6.4.1.
I also search for workaround and tried the following solutions, but nothing works,

`npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
npm install`

I tried to create the project, and getting the following error

[image]

Comment: It *is* being installed. Those warnings and harmless.

Comment: But, @KirkLarkin angular/cli is not being installed. When try to create angular project it throwing error like package install failed.

Comment: What happens when you try typing  ng -v  or  ng version ?